# Hash with Array values in Perl 6

Tags: raku

What's going on here?

Why are `%a{3}` and `%a{3}.Array` different if `%a` has `Array` values and `%a{3}` is an `Array`?

```perl6
> my Array %a
{}
> %a{3}.push("foo")
[foo]
> %a{3}.push("bar")
[foo bar]
> %a{3}.push("baz")
[foo bar baz]
> .say for %a{3}
[foo bar baz]
> %a{3}.WHAT
(Array)
> .say for %a{3}.Array
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference being observed here is the same as with:

```
my $a = [1,2,3];
.say for $a;        # [1 2 3]
.say for $a.Array;  # 1\n2\n3\n
```

The `$` sigil can be thought of as meaning "a single item". Thus, when given to `for`, it will see that and say "aha, a single item" and run the loop once. This behavior is consistent across `for` and **operators and routines**. For example, here's the zip operator given arrays and them itemized arrays:

```
say [1, 2, 3] Z [4, 5, 6];    # ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
say $[1, 2, 3] Z $[4, 5, 6];  # (([1 2 3] [4 5 6]))
```

By contrast, **method calls and indexing operations** will always be called on what is inside of the `Scalar` container. The call to `.Array` is actually a no-op since it's being called on an `Array` already, and its interesting work is actually in the act of the method call itself, which is unwrapping the `Scalar` container. The `.WHAT` is like a method call, and is telling you about what's inside of any `Scalar` container.

The values of an array and a hash are - by default - `Scalar` containers which in turn hold the value. However, the `.WHAT` used to look at the value was hiding that, since it is about what's inside the `Scalar`. By contrast, `.perl` [1] makes it clear that there's a single item:

```
my Array %a;
%a{3}.push("foo");
%a{3}.push("bar");
say %a{3}.perl;      $["foo", "bar"]
```

There are various ways to remove the itemization:

```
%a{3}.Array     # Identity minus the container
%a{3}.list      # Also identity minus the container for Array
@(%a{3})        # Short for %a{3}.cache, which is same as .list for Array
%a{3}<>         # The most explicit solution, using the de-itemize op
|%a{3}          # Short for `%a{3}.Slip`; actually makes a Slip
```

I'd probably use `for %a{3}<> { }` in this case; it's both shorter than the method calls and makes clear that we're doing this purely to remove the itemization rather than a coercion.

While `for |%a{3} { }` also works fine and is visually nice, it is the only one that doesn't optimize down to simply removing something from its `Scalar` container, and instead makes an intermediate `Slip` object, which is liable to slow the iteration down a bit (though depending on how much work is being done by the loop, that could well be noise).

---

[1] Based on what I wrote, one may wonder why `.perl` can recover the fact that something was itemized. A method call `$foo.bar` is really doing something like `$foo<>.^find_method('bar')($foo)`. Then, in a `method bar() { self }`, the `self` is bound to the thing the method was invoked on, removed from its container. However, it's possible to write `method bar(\raw-self:) { }` to recover it exactly as it was provided.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is `Scalar` containers do DWIM indirection.

`%a{3}` is bound to a `Scalar` container.

By default, if you refer to the value or type of a `Scalar` container, you actually access the value, or type of the value, *contained* in the container.

In contrast, when you refer to an `Array` container as a single entity, you do indeed access that `Array` container, no sleight of hand.

To see what you're *really* dealing with, use `.VAR` which shows what a variable (or element of a composite variable) is bound to rather than allowing any container it's bound to to pretend it's not there.

```
say %a{3}.VAR ;       # $["foo", "bar", "baz"]
say %a{3}.Array.VAR ; # [foo bar baz]
```

This is a hurried explanation. I'm actually working on a post specifically focusing on containers.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure that I already understand everything. So is adding `.Array` is the best way to deal with the problem? And why is `%a{3}` bound to a `Scalar` container if its values are explicitly declared as `Array`?

Comment: I'm writing a post about containers so everyone can understand them. They're beautiful and simple but need careful writing to bring that out. I hope to have it ready this weekend. The core issue here is, is an array a single thing? Or is it a bunch of things? It's both. So what do you mean when you say `for array`? P6 says that every single thing can be handled as a single thing if you wish to do that. And every plural thing can be handled as a plural thing *or a single thing*, whichever you prefer. But you must disambiguate. I might write `.say for |%a{3}` rather than `.say for %a{3}.Array`.

Comment: Thanks, `|` looks better! And please let me know when your post is ready.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky I'll let you know when my containers post is ready. In the meantime, if there's anything you're still curious about, please ask questions relative to jnthn's awesome answer by posting comments there. (I'm tempted to delete this answer because it was hurried and not especially helpful and now there's jnthn's answer. Do you see any reasons not to?)

Comment: Please don't delete your answer.